# How do I go about finding a probability of an event in R?

Tags: r, probability

In an experiment, a participant can either press a red button or a blue button. In a hypothetical situation, the probability of a participant pressing the red button (the event of interest) is 57% and each participants are independent of one another. If the experiment consisted of 100 participants, what is the probability that 57 participants will press the red button?

How would I write an R code to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

This follows binomial distribution: `dbinom(57, 100, 0.57)`.